# How to configure Firefox to only try opening an URL if it really looks valid and search it if it doesn't?

Tags: firefox, dns, browser, search, web

I have just entered `time.gmttime()` in the Firefox location bar intending to search for documentation on [this Python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime). And the response was `We can’t connect to the server at www.time.gmttime().` For me myself it is immediately obvious that `time.gmttime()` is not a server name as I look at it and even `time.gmttime` is not - theoretically a TLD named `.gmttime` can exist but the probability of a web site I would want to visit being registered in such a strange zone is near zero.

Can I configure Firefox to always consider the text typed in the location bar a search request in cases when the part that can be considered a server name is neither an IP address nor ends with a known existing TLD?

Comment: Not sure how firefox uses searches, given that it has been a long time ago since I used firefox, but if I remember correctly, there is a search bar too. Entering anything there will always search. In addition, many browsers allow searching by typing a letter in the addressbar. Vivaldi and Opera allow `g your search` to always search with google. Firefox may have a similar method.